# How to Re-Open Questions Labeled as `Closed`

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have noticed that some questions on the platform have been closed, most likely because OPs have not responded to comments asking for clarification or additional information.

As far as I understand, if someone wants to answer a closed question, they are supposed to modify the question, submit the revision, and then have it reopened by the site moderators (please correct me if I am mistaken).

Now, my question is: What if someone wants to provide an answer without modifying the question, in order to preserve its originality?

My suggestion: Shall we have alternative ways to reopen old questions without going through that process and have the question automatically reopened upon receiving an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does it say that users must modify the question in order to re-open it?

If there is a question that was closed due to being "abandoned" or because it "needs more clarity" and you are able to answer it, then you can click "flag" on the question, then "In need of moderator intervention", then just let the diamond moderation team know that you are able to answer the question.

Ideally it would then be opened within 24 hours.

You can also just click "reopen" and this will allow the question to enter the review queue: once four other users with enough points to access that part of the review queue, vote for the question to be re-opened, the question will be re-opened. By adding a comment explaining your reason for voting to re-open the question, you will be helping your peer reviewers to make their decision.

Comment: Thank you! It is my bad, I totally missed that reopen button.

Comment: In the case of voting 'reopen', it may be useful to leave a comment under the question to clarify the reason for reopening. Because otherwise it may look like the question is still abandoned.

Comment: @Anyon. Alright I got that, thank you.